# Spring JPA one to many join

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

```java
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class IndieApp {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "indie_app_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "indieApp")
    private List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class Genre {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "genre_id")
    private Long genreId;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description; //like "RPG", "Action"

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "indie_app_id")
    private IndieApp indieApp;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class RandomRecDto {
    private final Long id;
    private final String name;
    private final String genres;
}
```

```java
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RandomRecRepository {

    private final EntityManager em;

    public List<RandomRecDto> findRandomApps() {
        return em.createQuery(
                "select new study.weba.studyJPA.dto.RandomRecDto(i.id, i.name, g.description)" +
                " from IndieApp i join i.genres g", RandomRecDto.class)
                .setMaxResults(12)
                .getResultList();
    }
}
```

Hello seniors!
When i put the dummy data as shown below,

| indie_app_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | App1 |
| 2 | App2 |

| genre_id | description | indie_app_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Action | 1 |
| 2 | RPG | 1 |
| 3 | FPS | 2 |
| 4 | Sport | 2 |

i can get result like this.

```
randomRecDto = RandomRecDto(id=1, name=App1, genres=Action)
randomRecDto = RandomRecDto(id=1, name=App1, genres=RPG)
randomRecDto = RandomRecDto(id=2, name=App2, genres=FPS)
randomRecDto = RandomRecDto(id=2, name=App2, genres=Sport)
```

However, result that i want is like this.

```
randomRecDto = RandomRecDto(id=1, name=App1, genres=Action, RPG)
randomRecDto = RandomRecDto(id=2, name=App2, genres=FPS, Sport)
```

I want to get description by array.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you get `IndieApp` entities and then convert them into your `RandomRecDto` DTO? This would even simplify your Repository that would handle `IndieApp` instead of `RandomRecDto`:

```
public interface IndieAppRepository extends JpaRepository<IndieApp, Long> {
    List<IndieApp> findTop12();
}
```

You may want to read more details about Spring Data in the following links:

- [Spring Data JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa)
- [Spring Data Repositories](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories)
- [Limiting query results with Spring Data JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results)
- [Defining Spring Data Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details)
- [Spring Data Repositories Query Keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! but i solve this problem using native query + qlrm.

Answer (score 0):

```java
JpaResultMapper jpaResultMapper = new JpaResultMapper();

String sql = "SELECT i.indie_app_id, i.name, group_concat(g.description separator ',') FROM indie_app AS i" +
                " JOIN genre AS g ON i.indie_app_id = g.indie_app_id" +
                " group by i.indie_app_id, i.name";

Query nativeQuery = em.createNativeQuery(sql);

List<RandomRecDto> results = jpaResultMapper.list(nativeQuery, RandomRecDto.class);
```